# Android uninstall app before boot completion

Tags: uninstallation

A strange one this. I have got myself into a situation where I think that a single apk is causing boot to fail. I have the same situation on a Nexus 4 and Nexus 7 running 4.4.

Running `adb install <com.myapp.package>` would hang - then the device would reboot - then would get stuck on `Android is upgrading...Optimising app 1 of 1`.

I can list packages through `adb shell` at this point - but uninstalling with

`pm uninstall <com.myapp.package>`

will just hang - presumably as the current process is doing something with that apk already.

If i try to boot into recovery at this point i get a dead android with a "no command" message.

Fastboot is locked on the device and its not rooted.

My only option at this point i think is to unlock fastboot but was wondering if im missing something.

EDIT: I just wiped via fastboot on one device and it works again - dont really want to do this on other device if poss

Thanks!

Comment: Start it in safe mode and remove your app.

Comment: @323go "If i try to boot into recovery at this point i get a dead android with a "no command" message."

Comment: No. Not recovery. Safe mode. Google it.

Comment: Ill admit I have never used safe mode! However it seems you can only access it via a long press on the 'power off' button (on a nexus 4) - which requires you to be able to boot in the first place - which is a bit useless for my purposes

Comment: Have you tried it? https://support.google.com/nexus/answer/2852139?hl=en - You can also take a powered-off device and hold volume-down *after* the logo appears to enter safe mode.

Comment: No I couldnt as the device wont get through the boot system. +1 for the getting to safe mode through the boot sequence - I didnt see that info anywhere. I went on the link you provided earlier and someone rang me from the link - they said it was not possible (but they are just reading from a script I guess). Now my device has decided it wont even power up but as soon as it changes its mind (it always does in the end) I will try it out. Thanks for the tip :)

Comment: Good luck. It's never fun when they break.

Comment: Unfortunately the boot into safe mode (which works on my nexus 7) does not work / does not disable the "optimising app..." step :( seems like a reset is inevitable!

Comment: Could that thing happen because of some ART (new 4.4 runtime) issue? Did you do any research in that direction? Just curious, I've never encountered this before..

Comment: Yeah I thought of that as I did have ART enabled on one of the devices previously (but 95% I disabled it again) - plus the other device definitely didnt use ART. Plus I can recreate on factory reset devices

Answer (score -1):

The application apk will be stored in /data/app/ or system/app/ you can navigate there and rm .apk, then reboot

Comment: that requires root - have updated question to state the device is not rooted